# Classifying the uses of to-infinitive and the -ing form

Tags: gerund-vs-infinitive, predicate-frames

I'm having some trouble to classify the use of the to-infinitive and the -ing form of the verb in the following sentences:

*"This problem has the potential **to be** really serious."*

I took a look at links such as [this](https://www.ef.com/wwen/english-resources/english-grammar/infinitive/), but no explanation seems to fit.

*"**Knowing** what we know today, we could have made a different choice."*

For this case, I refered to this [link](https://academicguides.waldenu.edu/writingcenter/grammar/verbforms), but also didn't find a convincing classification. It seems like knowing would be a noun in that case? I'm not entirely sure. I would also like to know what is the "syntactic role" (not sure if this is the correct term) of "knowing" in the clause above. Is it a subject? An object? Sorry, it's very unclear to me because the structure of the clause is short-circuiting my brain.

Thanks!

EDIT: So, I figured out that the first example is an example of using the to-infinitive as a "postmodifier", as per this [link](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/grammar/english-grammar-reference/to-infinitives). I still have no clue about how to classify the second sentence though. If anyone has a suggestion, it is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Actually, "I'm having some trouble to classify" has to be "I'm having some trouble (in) classifying" using the gerund not the infinitive. On the hand, if you had said "I'm finding it hard to classify" then that one has to take the infinitive not the gerund. Because English uses both kinds of non-finite verb forms as nominal elements like subject—but which has to be used where varies by verb/predicate frame, it's much harder than in languages like Spanish where only the infinitive can be a subject or object and the adverbial gerund is reserved to modifier roles or continuous "tenses".

Comment: Thanks for the observation @tchrist! I actually solved part of the problem myself. In this [link](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/grammar/english-grammar-reference/to-infinitives) it is explained that the first usage is an example of a postmodifier! I'm still not sure about the second sentence I provided though.

Comment: The second link is a fronted participial phrase, like _Standing on the corner, there was a lamppost_. Whether to use an infinitive or an _ing_ form depends on the predicate (adjective, noun, or verb) and also on what construction it's being used in. Both of them can occur as subjects (with some verbs), objects (with some verbs), and objects of prepositions. And they occur also in all kinds of constructions, like _going to V, have to V, like Ving/to V, enjoy Ving, want to V,_ etc. There are also purpose infinitives like _He stopped to smoke_.

Comment: @JohnLawler thank you so much sir! Your answer was very helpful. In that case then, "knowing" is not a gerund, but a Present Participle, is that correct? In this case, would it be an adjective in the sentence that I exemplified?

Comment: I would call any _ing_ clause or phrase a gerund if it's a subject or object -- acting like a noun phrase. Otherwise I'd call it a participle. It's just a difference in terminology.

Comment: @JohnLawler I understand that, but according to this [link](https://www.grammar-monster.com/glossary/present_participle.htm), present participle phrases are adjectives. The whole phrase acts as an adjective. What is not clear to me is if the present participle INSIDE the participle phrase is also an adjective. Is that possible?

Comment: @RicardoMaia For most phrases, the function that you attribute to the phrase can also be said to apply to the phrase's head. If a present participle (such as "knowing") heads an adjectival phrase, then the present participle is often said to be functioning adjectivally, too. (Some people might take issue over dependency grammars vs. phrase-structure grammars, etc., but that gets down into the weeds.)

Comment: @RicardoMaia Guess what? That link is wrong. Some are adjectives, some are adverbs, some are nouns. Anybody at all, whether they know English syntax well or not, can say anything they like about English grammar, and somebody will believe them. So don't look for grammar definitions on the web; they're almost guaranteed to be wrong. Grammar is **complicated**, and broad general statements like "present participle phrases are adjectives" are good evidence of incompetence.

Comment: The most important point for Spanish and Portuguese speakers is to learn to use gerund nouns as subjects: **Surfing is fun**. The second (for intermediate learners) is to learn when you can use V + ing versus V + to. That is: *I like to play tennis*. and *I like playing tennis*. are the same in everyday speech (but **not** for picky grammarians).  verbs of liking/disliking such as like, hate, love, dislike can go both ways. Whereas "enjoy" or "detest" cannot "take" **to**. And there's more of that lurking around, too.

Comment: Thank you all for the kind replies! Very helpful indeed. I guess the most instructive part of this exercise was illuminating the differences between participles and gerunds.

Answer (score 1):

> [1] *This problem has the potential* [*to be really serious*].
>
> [2] [*Knowing what we know today*]*, we could have made a different choice*.

"Be" and "knowing" are both verbs.

In [1] the infinitival clause is a **complement** licensed by the noun "potential".

In [2] the gerund-participial clause is an **adjunct** in clause structure, more specifically an adjunct of 'implicated reason': it can be interpreted as giving the reason for the matrix situation.